# Grouping array by item of another array in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, arrays, grouping

I have 2 array in NodeJS:

```
var dataCms = ["BIG BIKE","CUB","MATIC","SPORT"];

var outJSON = [
            {
                "id": "42513b49-9bd8-11e9-a417-560001ead144",
                "series": "GENIO",
                "cms": "MATIC"
            },
            {
                "id": "5d8ae0f0-cda0-4c1d-be01-1bfd422a3cf4",
                "series": "VARIO",
                "cms": "MATIC"
            },
            {
                "id": "5d8ae0f0-cda0-4c1d-be01-1bfd422a3cf4",
                "series": "BEAT",
                "cms": "MATIC"
            },
            {
                "id": "5d8ae0f0-cda0-4c1d-be01-1bfd422a3cf4",
                "series": "SUPRA",
                "cms": "CUB"
            },
            {
                "id": "5d8ae0f0-cda0-4c1d-be01-1bfd422a3cf4",
                "series": "SONIC",
                "cms": "SPORT"
            },
            {
                "id": "5d8ae0f0-cda0-4c1d-be01-1bfd422a3cf4",
                "series": "REVO",
                "cms": "CUB"
            },
            {
                "id": "5d8ae0f0-cda0-4c1d-be01-1bfd422a8900",
                "series": "GENIO",
                "cms": "MATIC"
            }
        ];
```

And I want to grouping array outJSON by array dataCms like this:

```
{
    "BIGBIKE":[],
    "CUB": [
        {
            "id": "5d8ae0f0-cda0-4c1d-be01-1bfd422a3cf4",
            "series": "SUPRA"
        },
        {
            "id": "5d8ae0f0-cda0-4c1d-be01-1bfd422a3cf4",
            "series": "REVO"
        }
    ],
    "MATIC": [
        {
            "id": "42513b49-9bd8-11e9-a417-560001ead144",
            "series": "GENIO"
        },
        {
            "id": "5d8ae0f0-cda0-4c1d-be01-1bfd422a3cf4",
            "series": "VARIO"
        },
        {
            "id": "5d8ae0f0-cda0-4c1d-be01-1bfd422a3cf4",
            "series": "BEAT"
        },
        {
            "id": "5d8ae0f0-cda0-4c1d-be01-1bfd422a8900",
            "series": "GENIO"
        }
    ],
    "SPORT": [
        {
            "id": "5d8ae0f0-cda0-4c1d-be01-1bfd422a3cf4",
            "series": "SONIC"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried like this:

```
    let groups = Object.create(null);
    
    outJSON.forEach(item => {
    if (!groups[item.cms]) {
         groups[item.cms] = [];
    }
    
    groups[item.cms].push({
         id: item.id,
         series: item.series
    });
            });
    
    let result =
         Object.entries(groups)
         .map(([k, v]) => ({[k] : v}));
    
         console.log(result);
         return res.json(groups);
```

But the result that i get is like this:

```
{
    "MATIC": [
        {
            "id": "42513b49-9bd8-11e9-a417-560001ead144",
            "series": "GENIO"
        },
        {
            "id": "5d8ae0f0-cda0-4c1d-be01-1bfd422a3cf4",
            "series": "VARIO"
        },
        {
            "id": "5d8ae0f0-cda0-4c1d-be01-1bfd422a3cf4",
            "series": "BEAT"
        },
        {
            "id": "5d8ae0f0-cda0-4c1d-be01-1bfd422a8900",
            "series": "GENIO"
        }
    ],
    "CUB": [
        {
            "id": "5d8ae0f0-cda0-4c1d-be01-1bfd422a3cf4",
            "series": "SUPRA"
        },
        {
            "id": "5d8ae0f0-cda0-4c1d-be01-1bfd422a3cf4",
            "series": "REVO"
        }
    ],
    "SPORT": [
        {
            "id": "5d8ae0f0-cda0-4c1d-be01-1bfd422a3cf4",
            "series": "SONIC"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want if item in dataCms don't have the same item in outJson still showing but have length 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should iterate over the values in `dataCms` to ensure they are all present as keys in your output. Then you can filter the values in `outJSON` based on the `cms` value and create an object which is the value from `outJSON` without the `cms` key to push into the result array:

```js
var dataCms = ["BIG BIKE", "CUB", "MATIC", "SPORT"];

var outJSON = [{
    "id": "42513b49-9bd8-11e9-a417-560001ead144",
    "series": "GENIO",
    "cms": "MATIC"
  },
  {
    "id": "5d8ae0f0-cda0-4c1d-be01-1bfd422a3cf4",
    "series": "VARIO",
    "cms": "MATIC"
  },
  {
    "id": "5d8ae0f0-cda0-4c1d-be01-1bfd422a3cf4",
    "series": "BEAT",
    "cms": "MATIC"
  },
  {
    "id": "5d8ae0f0-cda0-4c1d-be01-1bfd422a3cf4",
    "series": "SUPRA",
    "cms": "CUB"
  },
  {
    "id": "5d8ae0f0-cda0-4c1d-be01-1bfd422a3cf4",
    "series": "SONIC",
    "cms": "SPORT"
  },
  {
    "id": "5d8ae0f0-cda0-4c1d-be01-1bfd422a3cf4",
    "series": "REVO",
    "cms": "CUB"
  },
  {
    "id": "5d8ae0f0-cda0-4c1d-be01-1bfd422a8900",
    "series": "GENIO",
    "cms": "MATIC"
  }
];

groups = dataCms.map(c => ({
  [c]: outJSON.filter(v => v.cms == c)
    .map(o => ({
      id: o.id,
      series: o.series
    }))
}));
console.log(groups);
```